# Delegate written in Swift not matching selector expected by Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm attempting to use an Objective C wrapper for a Flickr API (ObjectiveFlickr). The wrapper works with an Objective-C code example. I'm trying to use it with Swift and as soon as the wrapper tries to find the first delegate method, it fails on this assertion.

```
NSAssert([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(flickrAPIRequest:didObtainOAuthRequestToken:secret:)],
    @"Delegate must implement the method -flickrAPIRequest:didObtainOAuthRequestToken:secret: to handle OAuth request token callback");            
[delegate flickrAPIRequest:self didObtainOAuthRequestToken:oat secret:oats];
```

Here's the delegate method signature.

```
class FlickrDelegate : NSObject, OFFlickrAPIRequestDelegate
{

    func flickrAPIRequest(inRequest:OFFlickrAPIRequest,
                          didObtainOAuthRequestToken inToken:String,
                          secret inSecret:String) {
    ...
    }
}
```

I'm a complete novice with what I'm trying to do, so perhaps I've made some terribly dumb mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set your delegate property on flickrAPIRequest class in viewdidload to receive messages from Flikr?

Comment: It looks like it was another type of cockpit error here. The debugger showed the delegate was not set, but that was due to some other errors I made with the use of the library. Thanks for your feedback on this.